# Is that a normal speed at least 100 ms from ajax call to controller function for jsonresult

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, controller

I am working on a widget and the widget will be load in client web page (I am using MVC 5).
The widget is generated in server side by sending a ajax call to server controller jsonresult function. And after the jsonresult is returned, will rendered in a div.

I just realized even I return an empty jsonresult from the server side, the call from ajax to server and gets result back always takes more than 100 millseconds. Is that a normal time? And how I can even improve it. Some codes for the ajax request:

javascript code:

```
var baseUrl = "//somewebsite.dev/widget/getwidget";
$.ajax({
           cache: false,
           url: baseUrl,
           headers: {
               'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
           },
           type: 'POST',
           dataType: "json",
           data: {
                culture: 'en-GB',
                widgetId: '',
                containerId: 'widgetContainer',
                layout: 'nice',
                openOption: 'redirect', 
           },
           success: function(data) {
               $("#widgetContainer").html(data.Widget);
           },
           error: function(e) {
               alert("Unknown error: " + e);
           }
       });
```

Server side:

```
public virtual JsonResult GetWidget(string openOption, string culture,
        string containerId, string widgetId, string layout){
    return new JsonpResult
        {
            Data = new { Widget = "" }
        };
    }
```

capture time from chrome-inspect:
[image]

Comment: "Normal" is relative. The response time depends on any number of factors, some of which are totally out of your control.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, the reason I wonder is I also get a js file from the same server, and that js file loading time only takes 20ms, but the empty ajax call takes almost 200ms. for a loading widget, it is just not that smooth.